# Is there any premise for Compounding Words in Spanish place names?

Tags: spanish, names, compounds

I'm trying to make a Fakemon (fanmade Pokemon) region based on Mexico, and I want to name a  number of the cities with Spanish-sounding names. I admit that I'm terrible at making names, so I use this name generator I found and then translate the names. Only a lot of the names are compounds, like "Bloodwind" and "Coppersheen", and when I translate them it comes out like "Viento de Sangre" or "Brillo de Cobre", which doesn't sound like a name, and I tried reorganizing it to be "Sangreviento" and "Cobrebrillo", but I don't know if that works. Does it, or should I try something else?

Comment: Look up univerbation. "A single word formed from a fixed expression of several words. For example, the single word albeit comes from the Middle English expression al be it, in which al means although." (Source: Wiktionary, Appendix: Glossary). Another example of univerbation in English is atonement = "at" + "one" + "ment".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is precedent for making placenames from compounds in Spanish and in Mexico:

*Villalobos, Matamoros, Monterrey, Aguascalientes, Nezahualcóyotl, Valladolid, Tenochtitlán, Buenaventura, Santiago, Pueblonuevo, Xochimilco, Cabañaquinta, Veracruz, Villaviciosa…*

That said, your suggested placenames don’t sound like realistic Mexican placenames for a few reasons:

- They don’t sound very realistic in English.
- Placenames in Mexico do often contain multiple words, like *San Juan Teotihuacán* or *Tlajomulco de Zúñiga*.
- Most one-word compounds in Spanish are either a noun and an adjective, or a verb and a noun, like *Matamoros* (*kills Moors* i.e. *Moorkiller*).
- Half the placenames in Mexico are from the indigenous languages of Mexico, not really from Spanish.
- Many placenames and person names from Spain, like *Guadalajara*, are from a non-Romance language like Basque, Celtic, Visigothic or Arabic, or from a language like Asturian or Leonese, not from Castilian Spanish.

Because truth is stranger than fiction, there are plenty of real Mexican placenames that are as gruesome or entertaining as *Vientosangriento*:

*Matanzas*, *Dolores*, *Salsipuedes*, *Válgame Dios*, *La Chingada*, *Tamaulipas*, *Tlatlauquitepec*, *La Dinamita*, *Parangaricutiro*, *Basaseachic*, *Xbox*…. And a few more that are not fit to print.

This does seem like something that a generative AI model like ChatGPT would be good at, especially if you can give it a few examples, both real and fictional, single or multiple words.